# Writing a Ruby/Rake task robot with authentication to download data that requires login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I wanna run an automatic task that download a document that requires login before the file is downloaded, alongside with some Linux command line. What can I do to achieve this with Ruby/Rake task/Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html)

Comment: Ah, overlooked this one. Thanks!